# let a and b be positive integers. show that the number of multiples of b in the sequence...

Tags: elementary-number-theory

let a and b be positive integers. Show that the number of multiples of b in the sequence, $\{a,2a,3a,\dotsc,ab\}$ is equal to $\gcd(a,b)$.

I do not know what's the meaning of the sequence.

Comment: by $(a,b)$ you mean the $gcd$ of $a,b$?

Comment: yes, the gcd of a,b

Comment: By 2a,3a,ab you mean $2a,3a,...ab$ I guess?

Comment: yes!that's right.

Comment: Ok,I just edited it so it will be clear :-)

Answer (score 1):

Let the gcd of $a,b$ be $d$. Then, each term in the sequence is divisible by $d$ (as $a$ is divisible by $d$). Thus, for any term to be divisible by $b$, we need another factor $\frac bd$ from the term other than $a$. The number of numbers less than $b$ which can provide with this factor are $\frac {b}{\frac{b}{d}} = d.$ Thus, the number of multiples of $b$ in the given sequence is $d$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $d=\gcd(a,b)$, $a=da'$, $b=db'$.  We know that  $a',b'$ are coprime, and we want to find all possible values $k  \enspace(1\le k\le b)$ such that $b\mid ka$.

This means that 
$$db'\mid kda'\iff b'\mid ka'\iff b\mid k $$
by Gauß's lemma, i. e. $\,k=lb'$ for some $l$, and the condition $1\le k\le b=db'$ translates into $1\le l\le d$.

This proves there are $d=\gcd(a,b)$ elements in the sequence.